# Custom enumerate label with short horizontal rule

Tags: enumerate, rules, enumitem

I'd like to make an enumerated list with a short line in front of the item label.  Like this:

_____ 1. Item #1 text 
_____ 2. Item #2 text 
_____ 3. Item #3 text

My original idea was to use this syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\rule{0.5in}{0.4mm}\arabic*.]
    \item Item 1 text
    \item Item 2 text
    \item Item 3 text
\end{enumerate}

Some intervening text before the list continues

\begin{enumerate}[label=\rule{0.5in}{0.4mm}\arabic*. resume]
    \item Item 4 text
    \item Item 5 text
    \item Item 6 text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But this won't compile for me at all.  It is throwing an error which shows that the `\rule` command is being rejected.  I've tried a few other things (using `\hrule` or just some underscores like this: `____`).

I'm out of ideas.  HELP!

Comment: I don't receive any errors. Could you provide the file version you're using in terms of [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). See [Which package version am I using?](http://goo.gl/sBfU5X)

Comment: I should have known...when in doubt, update the packages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was resolved via a package/distribution update.

Comment: I agree with your assessment.  I'm wondering if it would be helpful to add a bit in the blurb about making questions to the effect of, "Make sure your packages are up to date," and some text about how to make sure of that (Like your link in the first comment).

Comment: Also, in order to update my packages, I actually had to uninstall TeXLive and reinstall TeXLive because my initial installation was via the debian package:  `sudo apt-get install texlive ` ...which means I'm relying on them to update my packages.  This seems less than ideal, which is why I went with [vanilla TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost works fine, except part of the  label is in the left margin. I added some keys to have it fit the left margin, added a thin space between the rule and the item numbers, and made the rule a little thinner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\rule{0.5in}{0.8pt}\,\arabic*., align=left, leftmargin=*]
    \item Item 1 text
    \item Item 2 text
    \item Item 3 text. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item. A long item.
\end{enumerate}

Some intervening text before the list continues

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
    \item Item 4 text
    \item Item 5 text
    \item Item 6 text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the most experienced of users, but this seems to work. instead of using `\rule`, I simply used underscore...

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textunderscore         \arabic*. resume]      
    \item Item 1 text     
    \item Item 2 text     
    \item Item 3 text 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```